# Question about sigma algebra generated by a countable sequence of sets

Tags: measure-theory

I have a question about the following problem from the book "A course in Probability theory" (chapter 2, problem 9).

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track!

For $k\in\mathbb N$ let $\Sigma_k = \{B \subseteq S \mid A_k \subseteq
B \lor B \cap A_k = \emptyset \}$.  It is easy to see that each
$\Sigma_k$ contains all $A_n$ for $n\in \mathbb N$ and is a
$\sigma$-algebra on $S$.  So each $\Sigma_k$ must be a superset of
$\Sigma$.  But $\Sigma_k$ by construction doesn't contain any
non-empty proper subsets of $A_k$ which implies that $\Sigma$ also
doesn't contain such sets (because $\Sigma$ only contains sets which
are in all $\Sigma_k$).

Now let $A$ be an arbitrary element of $\Sigma$.  We already know from
above that $A \subsetneq A_k$ for some $k$ is not possible.  Let's
assume $A \cap A_k\neq \emptyset$ and $A_k \nsubseteq A$ for some $k$.
Then, as both $A$ and $A_k$ are elements of $\Sigma$, $A \cap A_k$
must be an element of $\Sigma$.  But $A \cap A_k$ is again a non-empty
proper subset of $A_k$ which is a contradiction.

We've shown that for all $n\in\mathbb N$ either $A_n \subseteq A$ or $A_n
\cap A=\emptyset$.  As $S$ is the disjoint union of all the $A_n$, $A$
must thus be the disjoint union of all $A_n$ which are subsets of $A$.

**Addendum:** Note that we didn't use anywhere that $\mathbb{N}$ is
countable.  In fact, if $\cal A$ is an arbitrary partition of $S$,
then each $A$ in the $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma_{\cal A}$ generated by
$\cal A$ is a union of elements of $\cal A$.

But what about the other way around?  Is each union of elements of
$\cal A$ an element of $\Sigma_{\cal A}$?  If ${\cal A}$ is countable
(including finite) this must obviously be so.  But for uncountable
${\cal A}$ this doesn't necessarily have to be the case:

Let $S=\mathbb R$ and ${\cal A}=\{x+\mathbb{N} \mid x \in [0,1) \}$
  (where $[0,1)$ is the half-open interval and $\mathbb N$ contains
    $0$).  $\cal A$ is a partition of $S$ consisting of uncountably
    many countable sets.  The collection $\Sigma_\omega$ of all
    countable and co-countable subsets of $\mathbb R$ is a superset of
    $\cal A$ and a $\sigma$-algebra, so $\Sigma_{\cal A}$ clearly
    can't contain any sets not in $\Sigma_\omega$.  But $\bigcup_{x
      \in [0,\frac12)} (x+\mathbb{N})$ is the union of elements of
      $\cal A$ and neither countable nor co-countable.

Comment: @user144840: Please roll back to the original version of your question.  Quoting a few lines of a textbook is fair use, you won't have any legal problems.  And without the quote the whole entry will become useless.

Comment: @user144840: Thanks, I'll fix the TeX.